# Kickstart install, RHEL "storage configuration failed:...... not enough space in file systems for the current software selection"

Tags: rhel, iso, kickstart

I'm building a RHEL (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) OVF from ISO on VMware ESXi using **packer**. To summarize very quickly, basically the packer mounts the `.iso` to VMware, and we are able to power the newly imported VM on and configure it to my teams specifications listed in the **kickstart** `.cfg` file, **then** we export it after its fully configured as an `.ovf` file. I'm running into I believe to be a **storage configuration** issue, but I have been increasing the values to no avail. Every other installation step looks like its fine and good to go.

This is the message below with screen shot also (ss is from terminal console of the VM (rhel) on the ESXi that is hosting it):

```
Checking software selection
Generating updated storage configuration
storage configuration failed: Unable to allocate requested partition scheme.
==============================================================================
Installation

 1) [x] Timezone settings                 2) [x] Language settings
        (America/New_York timezone)              (English (United States))
 3) [x] Installation source               4) [x] Software selection
        (Local media)                            (Custom software selected)
 5) [!] Install Destination               6) [x] Network settings
        (Error checking storage configu          (Wired (eth0) connected)
        ration)                           8) [x] Create user
 7) [x] Kdump                                    (No user will be created)
        (Kdump is enabled)'

Not enough space in file systems for the current software selection. An additional 1371.61 MiB is needed.

Enter 'b' to ignore the warning and attempt to install anyway.

  Please make your choice from above ['q' to quit | 'b' to begin installation |
  'r' to refresh]: 
[anaconda] 1:main* 2:shell  3:log  4:storage-log  5:program-log
```

[image]

This is an except from our kickstart `.cfg` file (below) where we specify the partitions. `part pv.01` is **36000** (the total size of the vg_root is 47269 I believe) but I still get the same exception message above:

```
bootloader --location=mbr --driveorder=sda --append="fips=1 crashkernel=auto rhgb quiet" --password=MySuperSecretPassword

zerombr
clearpart --all --initlabel --drives=sda,sdb

part /boot --fstype=ext4 --size=512
part pv.01 --size=36000 --grow --ondrive=sda
part pv.02 --size=1000 --grow --ondrive=sdb

volgroup vg_root pv.01
volgroup vg_perstore pv.02

logvol / --fstype=xfs --name=lv_root --vgname=vg_root --size=7000 --grow
logvol /export/home --fstype=xfs --name=lv_home --vgname=vg_root --size=1000
logvol /opt --fstype=xfs --name=lv_opt --vgname=vg_root --size=4096
logvol /tmp --fstype=xfs --name=lv_tmp --vgname=vg_root --size=2048
logvol /var --fstype=xfs --name=lv_var --vgname=vg_root --size=2048
logvol /var/core --fstype=xfs --name=lv_core --vgname=vg_root --size=128
logvol /var/crash --fstype=xfs --name=lv_crash --vgname=vg_root --size=1000
logvol /var/getlogs --fstype=xfs --name=lv_getlogs --vgname=vg_root --size=2000
logvol /var/viewlogs --fstype=xfs --name=lv_viewlogs --vgname=vg_root --size=1000
logvol /var/log --fstype=xfs --name=lv_log --vgname=vg_root --size=1000
logvol /var/log/audit --fstype=xfs --name=lv_audit --vgname=vg_root --size=725
logvol /var/log/logins --fstype=xfs --name=lv_logins --vgname=vg_root --size=96
logvol /var/log/root_logins --fstype=xfs --name=lv_root_logins --vgname=vg_root --size=32
logvol /var/cache/yum --fstype=xfs --name=lv_repo --vgname=vg_root --size=1000
logvol /var/opt/BurgerKing --fstype=xfs --name=lv_varopt --vgname=vg_root --size=20000
logvol swap --name=lv_swap --vgname=vg_root --size=4096
logvol /var/opt/perstore --fstype=xfs --name=lv_perstore --vgname=vg_perstore --size=500 --grow
```

And then we specify the VM disk size and some other configuration for the actual VM (RHEL ISO) in the *packer* config `.json` file (below). I removed all the other data and just left the important sizing information for clarity. `disk_size` property is at **48000**:

```
{
  "builders": [
    {
      "disable_vnc": true,
      "type": "vmware-iso",
      "guest_os_type": "rhel7-64",
      "headless": true,
      "disk_type_id": "thin",
      "disk_size": 48000,
      "disk_additional_size": 2000,
      "shutdown_command": "systemctl enable firstboot.service && init 0",
      "keep_registered": "false",
      "skip_export": "false",
      "format": "ovf",
      "output_directory": "/output/",
      "vmx_data": {
        "numvcpus": "2",
        "memsize": "4096"
      }
    }
  ],
  "provisioners": [
  ]
}
```

Do I still have the partitions misconfigured? You can see if I manually hit `5.` on the keyboard and bypass this menu it shows the `sda` and `sdb` partitions and some sizes:
[image]

Comment: That partition strategy seems really crazy to me.

Comment: @jordanm Yes. I didn't write it. I'm more a Java coder, but on a team with a lot of Linux stuff so this is what was given to me. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, the location that most stuff actually gets installed to (/usr), which is still on your / partition despite having 17 partitions. That only has 7GB allocated to it. Try increasing that.

Comment: @jordanm This is for a company and very niche RHEL running on a specific entity, so yeah, it won't be like a normal Linux installation where the /usr has a lot of files in it.

Comment: The OS itself installs to /usr, doesn't matter what your internal applications do

Comment: Oh , I didn't know that. That's part of my problem - where is this low space coming from ? /dev/sda? /dev/sdb? I'm confused where to even look (linux newb here)

Comment: The logic volume "lv_root".

Comment: sigh, yeah  I added 15000 and still nothing. I even removed all of that kickstart file up to the "clearpart" declaration and it still shows the same message, which I'm not sure how. I increased the VM size to like 200,000 and others to crazy high values but its still doing this. I don't know enough about RHEL but it seems like something else is FUBAR here

Answer (score 1):

Figured out. My kickstart file was never being used ('Doh). Fixed my files and once it found my kickstart file, we were good to go.

Comment: Maybe you can add more details? What exactly did you fix?

Comment: @ennth can how exactly you fixed this. I am also stuck with same issue.